# FCM Downstream message via Android - No notification?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to send a downstream message via android. I get the Response Code 200
but I don't get a notification. It is possible to send the notifications
via firebase console, I checked this already.

This is the code of my Post-Request:

```
 public class DownstreamMessage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
    AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    int responseCode;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String server_key = "key=12345";
        String client_key;
        String content;
        String content_json_string;


        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            client_key = params[0];

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", server_key);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.connect();





            JSONObject notification_json_object = new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                notification_json_object.put("body","Hello World");
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject content_json_object = new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                content_json_object.put("to",client_key);
                    content_json_object.put("notification",notification_json_object);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            content_json_string = content_json_object.toString();

            OutputStream output = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(content_json_string.getBytes());
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();


        }
        catch (ProtocolException e)
        {

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }

        return "" + responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

This is MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
    {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    public void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getFrom())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                //.setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().toString())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here ist my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
         </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".InstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCEID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

I hope you can help me!
Best Regards,
Felix

Comment: can you post your android manifest xml ?

Comment: yes, I edited my entry

Comment: do you able to create a token ?

Comment: yes, and I am able to send notifications via console

Comment: check my answer if it helps you

Comment: does it works for you?

Comment: Your post request is missing a "data" field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you made small mistake here ..

Typo in your manifest instance id service intent filter. check the below code.

Replace your

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCEID_EVENT"/>
```

with

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
```

and try again.

**NOTE :**

> 1. Try exiting / close your app and check from Firebase console. You will receive the notification by default. you don't need to write
>      logic to create notification here.
> 2. If your app is running and you received the notification, it will not appear as like above but can be able to print it in a log cat and
>      check.

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: thank you, that explains, why onTokenRefresh wasn't called, but I still don't get a notification. And now via console doesn't work too

Comment: does your app is in foreground or background ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works now! You were right.  It was in the foreground. I can see my own notification in the logcat.